# LASSO CV monotonically decreasing in lambda?

Tags: cross-validation, lasso

I am using Matlab's lassoglm function to select the best logit specification from a set of 25 covariates. I am using time series data and have around 500,000 observations.

My CV plot shows the error decreases monotonically with lambda (graph below). Any idea why this could be? My covariates are significant predictors in the literature, and all (or most) are significantly correlated with my dependent variable. Is a univariate specification really the best model? I am struggling to believe that. The coefficient path is below for reference. I would appreciate some thoughts.

[image: LASSO CV Plot]

[image]

Comment: I don't know how MATLAB selects the set of regularization values, but it seems that the range doesn't coincide with the more typical "swoosh" behavior that shows the transition from under- to over-fitting. Have you tried giving it a different set of regularization values, perhaps $[10^{-6}, 1]$?

Comment: @Sycorax: $10^{-4}$ seems to be the value of lambda for which the first variable gets a coefficient different from zero. The fact that I don't get the typical "swoosh" behavior is what I am confused about, since it indicates that the univariate model is the best model (contrary to other similar studies in the bankruptcy prediction field, which tend to have at least 7 predictors).

Comment: From the second plot, it seems like even when the other covariates become active, their values remain very close to zero. That is, even the unconstrained regression has these coefficients being small. (Besides those two that veer upward.) Perhaps this somehow suggests that they're not very useful in prediction.

Comment: How do these results compare to an ordinary regression?

Comment: @Sycorax: I can achieve better prediction power (as measured by area under the ROC curve) by hand-picking 5 or 6 variables than with the one variable the LASSO suggests. Adding the next couple of variables chosen by LASSO still doesn't beat my hand-picked set. Thank you both (@Ben) for your help.